# Necessity of flu shots under pandemic living conditions

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, influenza

Is the following logic valid?

Getting an influenza vaccine is less necessary this season, if one is going to live under conditions (mask-wearing, drastically reduced contacts with others etc) designed to minimise exposure to COVID-19, but that also have the (beneficial) side-effect of minimising exposure to viruses in general, including influenza ones.

Could the case be made for the flu shot still being necessary if living conditions return to normal for the second half of the season, i.e. after one has resumed social contacts while still being in the protection time-window of the flu shot?

Answer (score 2):

> Could the case be made for the flu shot still being necessary if living conditions return to normal for the second half of the season

Yes, one argument would be that even with the current precautions, there are still currently half a million new covid cases daily, so it's preferable to have only one pandemic instead of two.